# CheckCXXCompilerFlag or CheckCCompilerFlag to check a group of flags at once

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm starting with `cmake`, I found this module/s with this macro/s, the docs says that this macro are checking 1 flag, but I also found out that a normal set of flags works just as fine as when you use 1 flag, for example

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11 -O3 -v" HAS_FLAG)
if (HAS_FLAG)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O3 -v")
endif()
```

This is good for me because it makes really easy to identify where I'm setting the flags for a given platform or compiler, a 1 by 1 check would easily be too tedious and verbose to be handy.

Is this a good way to write a `CMakeLists.txt` ? There are possible drawbacks when checking multiple flags at once ?

Answer (score 2):

Besides that if your check will fail, you wouldn't able to identify which particular flag caused it - no, there are no drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on this; If you want to make sure a certain flag doesn't produce a warning, you can specify the first argument like so (for clang/gcc):

```
check_cxx_compiler_flag("-Werror <flag>" <variable>)
```